# How do I stop the cell fill colors from being revealed on Google Sheets before Conditional Formatting takes effect?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with a set of cells filled in various colors. I currently have conditional formatting set up to cover my background colors with white unless the specific condition is met where two cells match. I'm using the custom conditional format rule: =$Y$7<>$B$2 and the range is a different group of cells. Everything seems to work except when the first item is entered, all of the background colors flash for a couple of seconds and the Sheet freezes before the cells are covered with white as expected. Then it works normally. I would love to find a way to NOT have the background colors shown until the conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more condition:

```
=($Y$7<>$B$2)*($Y$7<>"")*($B$2<>"")
```